# Extending the domain of the yoneda embedding map from étale schemes to the small étale topos so that it is still fully faithful

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, etale-cohomology

Let $X$ be a scheme. For $Y$ a scheme over $X$, the representable presheaf $h_Y : U\mapsto \mathrm{Hom}_X(U,Y)$ on the small étale site $X_{et}$ is actually a sheaf, and by the Yoneda lemma the mapping $Y\to h_Y$ is fully faithful when restricted to the category of schemes étale over $X$. Is there a bigger subcategory of the schemes over $X$ such that it is still fully faithful ?

Similarly, what about algebraic spaces over $X$ ? Seing those as sheaves on the big fppf site of $X$, we can restrict them to the small étale site. This is operation is fully faithful when done on algebraic spaces that are étale schemes, can we get a bigger subcategory for which it is still fully faithful ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The good setting to answer this question really is that of algebraic spaces. Then I believe that the answer is no, basically because every sheaf $F$ on the small étale site is representable by an étale $X$-algebraic space. The algebraic space that represents $F$ is constructed as follows: consider the collection of pairs $(V,x)$ with $V$ an affine étale $X$-scheme and $x\in F(V)$. Let $U$ be the disjoint sum of the $V$'s indexed by this collection. If $(V,x)$ and $(V',x')$ are two pairs, the natural morphism $V\times_FV'\to V\times_XV'$ is an open immersion. This shows that $U\times_FU$ is open in $ U\times_X U$ and hence defines an étale equivalence relation on $U$. The $X$-algebraic space we're looking for is the quotient of this equivalence relation.

This is due to Michael Artin, reference: his book "Théorèmes de représentabilité pour les espaces algébriques", chap. VII. Le théorème de finitude en cohomologie étale, §1. Définition des faisceaux constructibles.